# Как добавить путь в переменную %PATH% Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Каким образом можно добавить путь в переменную глобально с помощью скрипта Python?

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/416087/

Comment: Данный код устарел. Он был опубликован 12 лет назад.

Comment: @0x00, код не устарел, переменные окружения все так же хранятся в реестре. Единственно, что код написан для Python 2, но это тоже не проблема.

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`, переменная `Path`. Прочитать, добавить, записать. Если прав хватит, конечно.

Comment: Прав не хватит :(

Comment: @0x00, если нужно именно глобально (в системный PATH, а не в пользовательский), то нужны права администратора.

Comment: Могу добавить ещё один вариант, но требуются права администратора. Выполнение из командной строки.
[Подробности тут](http://ab57.ru/cmdlist/set.html)

Answer (score 1):

### Прежде всего, что нужно знать:

- Переменные окружения текущего пользователя хранятся в реестре в `HKCU\Environment`
- Общесистемные (общие для всех пользователей) переменные окружения хранятся в реестре в `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`, для записи в системные переменные окружения (в том числе в `PATH`) нужны права администратора.

### Простой вариант

Если просто нужно добавить что-то в пользовательский `PATH` одной функцией:

```
import winreg

def add_to_path(path, root=winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, key_path='Environment', access=winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS):
    root_key = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, root)
    key = winreg.OpenKey(root_key, key_path, 0, access)
    value, value_type = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, 'path')
    value = value.rstrip(';') + ';' + path
    winreg.SetValueEx(key, 'path', 0, value_type, value)
    winreg.CloseKey(key)
    winreg.CloseKey(root_key)

add_to_path(r'C:\Test Path')
```

### Более сложный вариант

В угоду богу велосипедостроения написал класс-обертку над модулем `winreg` с менеджером контекста:

```
import winreg

HKCR = winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
HKCC = winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG
HKCU = winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER
HKLM = winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
HKU = winreg.HKEY_USERS


class RegistryKey:
    def __init__(self, root, path: str, access=winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS):
        self._root_key = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, root)
        self._key = winreg.OpenKey(self._root_key, path, 0, access)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def close(self):
        if hasattr(self, '_key') and self._key:
            winreg.CloseKey(self._key)
            self._key = None

        if hasattr(self, '_root_key') and self._root_key:
            winreg.CloseKey(self._root_key)
            self._root_key = None

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.close()

    def __del__(self):
        self.close()

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(1024):
            try:
                n, v, _ = winreg.EnumValue(self._key, i)
            except (OSError, EnvironmentError):
                break

            yield n, v

    def __getitem__(self, name: str):
        return winreg.QueryValueEx(self._key, name)[0]

    def __setitem__(self, name: str, value):
        value_type = winreg.QueryValueEx(self._key, name)[1]
        winreg.SetValueEx(self._key, name, 0, value_type, value)
```

Пример работы с переменной `PATH` пользователя:

```
with RegistryKey(HKCU, 'Environment') as key:
    old_path = key['path']
    # Добавляем путь в переменную PATH
    key['path'] = key['path'].rstrip(';') + ';' + r'C:\Test Path'
    # Так тоже будет работать, но в PATH может случайно оказаться две точки с запятой:
    key['path'] += ';' + r'C:\Test Path'
    print(key['path'])
    input('Press Enter...')

    # Восстанавливаем старый PATH
    key['path'] = old_path
    print(key['path'])
```

Соответственно, для работы с системным `PATH` нужно использовать `RegistryKey(HKLM, r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment')`.

Ответ основан на скрипте по ссылке из первого комментария к вопросу: [code.activestate.com/recipes/416087](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/416087)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте напрямую средства ОС - запускайте power shell скрипты с необходимыми командами

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
import subprocess, sys

p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", 
          "C:\\temp\\script1.ps1"], 
          stdout=sys.stdout)
```

Далее примеры power shell скриптов

Чтобы добавить пользовательскую переменную используйте:

```
Set-ItemProperty "hkcu:\Environment" MY_PATH1 "d:\temp"
```

Чтобы добавить системную переменную (запускать “Run as Administrator”):

```
Set-ItemProperty "hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" MY_PATH2 "c:\project"
```

Чтобы добавить путь в переменную PATH используйте:

```
$Path = "d:\temp"
$envPaths = $env:Path -split ';'
if ($envPaths -notcontains $Path) {
    $envPaths = $envPaths + $Path | where { $_ }
    $new_path = $envPaths -join ';'
    Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" PATH $new_path
}
```

Comment: Использовать скрипт, чтобы запустить другой скрипт, чтобы произвести запись в реестр - это слегка оверкилл

Comment: одна и та же программа на windows запускает power shell на linux bash-скрипты, тащить инородный код в python-сценарии предлагаете?

Comment: Обращение к реестру - это не инородный код, данный функционал есть в стандартной библиотеке Python. Вообще, я к тому, что если использовать powershell, то нет смысла использовать Python. И наоборот.

Comment: А у меня получается, если можно использовать что-то "родное", специально для этого предназначенное - нужно использовать. Нет привязки к конкретному языку. Есть иллюзия, что таким образом экономлю время.

Comment: В итоге запускаете 2 интерпретатора, каждый из которых стартует не мгновенно, чтобы в конце концов обратиться к реестру через winapi. `"Нет привязки к конкретному языку"` - powershell тоже язык. `"если можно использовать что-то "родное""` - давайте тогда уж писать на Си или Ассемблере, они для системы более родные, чем интерпретатор powershell или python.

Comment: допустим есть голый windows сервер, поставить вы туда ничего не можете, с помощью чего установить переменные среды? с помощью ассемблера? я же хотел экономить время

Comment: Если вернуться к исходному вопросу, то уже установлен (по крайней мере можно запустить) Python. Экономим время - делаем запись в реестр сразу в скрипте на Python.

Comment: P.S. с помощью ассемблера - элементарно, не сложнее чем на Си.