cx_freeze перенос файлов в другую директорию
В ДОКУМЕНТАЦИИ НЕ НАШЕЛ!!!!
setup.py выглядет так
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

executables = [Executable(script="main.py", target_name="test.exe", 
               icon='ico.ico', base='gui']

excludes = []

includes = []

options = {
'build_exe': {
    'include_msvcr': True,
    'excludes': excludes,
    'includes': includes,
    'build_exe': 'build_Windows',
   }
}

setup(name='test',
   version='1.2.5',
   description='ttt',
   executables=executables,
   options=options)

тк стоит include_msvcr то соответственно в директории с .exe копируется миллион файлов msvcr. Мне нужно чтобы эти файлы были перемещены в папку lib в этой-же директорию.
Как выглядет папка после сборки сейчас: 
Как мне нужно: 
Чтобы все зависимости msvcr были перемещены в папку lib (ручное перемещение не канает - .exe не работает на устройствах без зависимостей Microsoft.VCRedist.2015+.x64 и Microsoft.VCRedist.2015+.x86 (если они не обновлены в том числе)
Список всех зависимостей, которые присутствуют есть в папке Windows Kit Tool, или ниже:
           ["api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-core-console-l1-2-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-core-file-l1-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-1-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-core-namedpipe-l1-1-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll", "api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-crt-private-l1-1-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll", 
            "api-ms-win-eventing-controller-l1-1-0.dll", "api-ms-win-eventing-provider-l1-1-0.dll"]


Из директории lib будет видеть dll только если эту директорию добавить в переменную окружения PATH.

@insolor а пример кода можете показать?

Тут например посмотрите: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/876016/1365
